# How to remove a hidden newline in Powershell when `n and `r don't work

Tags: powershell

Trying to make a 1 liner to do the below (Limitation of the system passing the script to Powershell)

Trying to turn eventlogs into a CSV string with no newlines to be read into a different language

Example code:

```
(get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation).replace("`"`"","`",`"")
```

shows:

```
"InstanceId","Index","EntryType","Message"

"2147489661","19981","Information","The system uptime is 961904 seconds."

"10000","19980","Error","The description for Event ID '10000' in Source 'DCOM' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'C:\Windows\System32\coredpussvr.exe -Embedding', '0', '{417976B7-917D-4F1E-8F14-C18FCCB0B3A8}'"
```

```
(get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation).contains("`r")
```

shows `False`

```
(get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation).contains("`n")
```

shows `False`

```
if ((get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation) -like "*`n*"){write-host "win"} 
if ((get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation) -like "*`r"){write-host "win"}
```

no luck on either

When I look at the result in a `CharArray` I can't see any characters between the displayed lines it just shows

```
onds." "10000
```

Which is why I tried the first example of inserting the `,` between the `""`  but there seems to be something forcing it into a newline.

When I try replacing the `""` with `","` with example code 1 in a test string it works fine

Any ideas?

Comment: the `.Contains()` array method seems to require an _exact_ match. is there an array item that is ONLY a `CR` or ``LF`?

Comment: when i run `Get-EventLog -LogName 'System' -Newest 2 | Select-Object -Property InstanceID, Index, EntryType, Message | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation` all i get is an array containing 3 lines of text. there is no `NewLine` char in there at all. how are you converting that array into a single string?

Comment: @Lee_Dailey
CSV conversion outputs a string.

`get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | get-member`

outputs typename: System.String

Comment: no it DOES NOT output a string! [*frown*] that is the info for one of the items in the result collection. save it to a $Var and then run `$Var.GetType()` on that.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey.
Curiously i get the same behaviour, it shows the output as a string when going to get-member, but if i save as an object, it saves as an array unless i hard declare as string which works fine
`Fixed with [string](get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation)`

Comment: ha! you have run into the way that PoSh unrolls collections with using the pipeline! [*grin*] sending to Get-Member via the pipeline will give info on the objects IN the collection. ///// take a look at the difference between `gm -InputObject @(1,2,3,4)` and `@(1,2,3,4) | gm` for a demo.

Comment: Makes Sense,  Curious though, even though i now have it as a string, i can't replace the " " with ","   `.Replace("`" `"","`",`"")`  works for the first, but not the rest, when they get rolled into a string, do they use a different character type?  the `[byte]$char` on it shows 32 which suggest it should be a space.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey

Curious, .Replace works once it is saved as a string object, but .replace doesn't work on the 1 liner. (the `'s keep getting stripped from my comment)
Any known difference between using .replace on a oneliner vs a string variable?

.replace fails but -replace works fine in the 1 liner, how odd

Comment: the `.Replace()` string method is a tad odd. i usually use the `-replace` string operator since that one uses regex and is a tad more predictable. [*grin*] ///// however, i would NOT use the method you used to "string-ify" the array. instead use `-join ','` on the collection.

Comment: as an aside - what do you mean by "one liner"? there are two common definitions ... [1] technical = code that fits on one line; may have delimiters where there would normally be line breaks. powershell uses semi-colons for this. ///// [2] actual = a single continuous line of code with NO line-ending items in it.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation
```

...is returning an array of strings. So, if you pipe it to "Get-Member", it's going to detect it's strings, so it'll tell you about strings. If you want to see what it literally is, you can type:

```
(get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation).GetType().FullName
```

If you want it all as a single string with carriage returns and line feeds, you could do this:

```
(get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation) -join "`r`n"
```

If you wanted to replace blank lines, you could add a "`Where-Object`" (alias: `?`) filter that filters out empty lines, as in:

```
get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | ? {$_}
```

If you want to do "Get-Member" on the collection, then make the collection inside a collection by pre-pending a comma, as in:

```
,(get-eventlog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation) | gm
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Because [ConvertTo-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) outputs a collection of strings, you can use the [join operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join) to create a single string with a separator character of your choice:

```
(Get-EventLog -LogName system -Newest 2 | select instanceid,index,entrytype,message | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation) -join ','
```